# How to associate function and checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I building UI for task manager app. I have a button `Get all tasks` on my page. When user click on this button he get list all tasks. Each task have checkbox with status `boolean done = true/false`. And when task print on page then each  checkbox of task have state in accordance with status of task.

When user click on checkbox then send ajax request to server which contain two values: `id` of task and new value of `done`.

But I have issue: when I click on checkbox for change `done` status then call all checkbox instead one checkbox which I click.

Help me fix this issue. Thank You.

This is code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //button id.
    $("#get_all_task_but").click(function(){

        // URL of servlet.
        $.ajax({
            url : 'get_all_tasks',
            type : "post",
            success : function (data) {
                var data = JSON.parse(data);


                $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

                    //insert HTML into DOM here
                    var checkboxName = 'checkbox'+value['id'];
                    var checkboxValue = value['desc'];
                    var checkboxHtml = '<input type="checkbox" name="'+checkboxName+'" value="'+checkboxValue+'" />';
                    $('#all_tasks').append(checkboxHtml);

                });

                $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e)
                {
                    //info on which checkbox is click in 'this' and the event object
                    //$(this) to get the checkbox as jQuery object
                    console.log('Send to server', this, e);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="result_from_server">
        <input name="data" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>

    <div id="resp"></div>

    <div>
        <input id="get_all_task_but" type="button" value="Get all task" />
        <ul id="all_tasks">

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: '<input type="checkbox">'  will select all elements whose input type is checkbox,hence you need to select only the checked  div.Can you post the dependent html code also?

Comment: @Hameed Syed I addition HTML code.

Comment: @Pavel Is it possible to get the browsers source code at runtime? It is just a shot into dark that the value of attribute id is same for all checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of listening for **click** event on the body, listen for a **change** event on the checkbox:

```
success : function (data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

        //insert HTML into DOM here
        var checkboxName = 'checkbox'+value['id'];
        var checkboxValue = value['desc'];
        var checkboxHtml = '<input type="checkbox" name="'+checkboxName+'" value="'+checkboxValue+'" />';
        $('#all_tasks').append(checkboxHtml);

    });

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e)
    {
       //info on which checkbox is click in 'this' and the event object
       //$(this) to get the checkbox as jQuery object
       console.log('Send to server', this, e); 
    });
}
```

Maybe target the checkbox via a class instead of `$('input[type="checkbox"]')`.

Don't use a click event if you want to measure whether or not the value has **changed**. That's what the change event is for.

Comment: but how to print my checkbox? I need variable for insert into foreach. What are You mean //insert HTML into DOM here? How Dom halp me?

Comment: DOM stands for Document Object Model, it's where your HTML lives. I've updated my answer to show how to add the checkboxes to the DOM. I'm not sure what exactly is in the `value` var so I made something up in terms of checkbox name and value.

Comment: when I click on Get all tasks then I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function` for `.on('change', function(e)`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere? The code I posted seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vnehkjsm/ 
Can you post your code?

Comment: I'm update my question add code which I take from You're answer. This code which fail in `.on('change', function(e)`

Comment: I don't really see an issue with the code. Can you `console.log($('input[type="checkbox"]'))` to see what that reports?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149399/discussion-between-meldon-and-pavel).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you are adding a listener to the doc, not the checkbox itself:

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
document.body.appendChild(checkbox); //you need to insert itin some point at the DOM tree

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     console.log('send to server');
});
```

Comment: I get : `Uncaught TypeError: checkbox.addEventListener is not a function` for place: `.addEventListener('click', function (e) {`

Comment: The reason is that checkbox was just a string: var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox">';

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jquery event listener on body with a selector to replace your event listener And then send the target's data to the server:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    console.log( $(e.target).val() );
}
```

Comment: I get: `Co Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined` for `$(body).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){`

Comment: My bad, forgot to put quotes ! 
I changed that, it should work now.